# 15 monohedral pentagonal tiles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I ask the question a few minutes ago: [New Pentagonal Tiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345368/new-pentagonal-tiling). 
([The 15th monohedral convex pentagonal type, discovered in 2015.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling))

I draw 15 type of pentagonal tilings and I just want to share these pentagons. Can I share my shapes here?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=1.1]
\foreach \x in {0,3,6,9,12,15} 
    \draw[line width=1pt,pink] (0,\x) -- (9,\x);
\foreach \x in {0,3,6,9}
    \draw[line width=1pt,pink] (\x,0) -- (\x,15);
\draw[line width=1pt,pink] (0,0) -- (9,0) -- (9,15) -- (0,15) -- cycle;  

\foreach \x in {0,3,6} 
  \foreach \y in {3,6,...,15}
  \draw[pink,line width=1pt] (\x,\y-.3) rectangle (\x+.3,\y);


\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,2.85)  node {\tiny $1$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,2.85)  node {\tiny $2$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,2.85)  node {\tiny $3$}; 


\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,5.85)  node {\tiny $4$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,5.85)  node {\tiny $5$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,5.85)  node {\tiny $6$}; 

\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,8.85)  node {\tiny $7$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,8.85)  node {\tiny $8$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,8.85)  node {\tiny $9$};

\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,11.85)  node {\tiny $10$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,11.85)  node {\tiny $11$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,11.85)  node {\tiny $12$};

\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,14.85)  node {\tiny $13$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,14.85)  node {\tiny $14$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,14.85)  node {\tiny $15$};


    \draw (1.5,1.5) node {
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 1
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (15:27mm) $) coordinate (B) node[right] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!26mm!-67:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!11mm!-113:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [left] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!17mm!-125:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,above right] {$c$};
\draw [green](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw (D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[red](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-.9) node{$\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=180^\circ$};
\draw (1,-1.5) node{$\widehat{A}+\widehat{D}+\widehat{E}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}    
    };

\draw (4.5,1.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 2
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (25:15mm) $) coordinate (B) node[right] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!14mm!-120:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!30mm!-95:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [left] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!14mm!-60:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [green](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [blue](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[red](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (.4,-.9) node{$c=e$};
\draw (.4,-1.5) node{$\widehat{B}+\widehat{D}=180^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,1.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 3
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (-18:24mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!8mm!-105:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!26mm!-120:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!18mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(C)!8mm!-120:(B)$) coordinate (BC);



\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [green](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above right] {$d$};
\draw (D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[blue] (C) -- (BC);
\draw (D) -- (BC);

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (BC) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1,-1.5) node{$a=b,\;d=c+e$};
\draw (1,-2.2) node{$\widehat{A}=\widehat{C}=\widehat{D}=120^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};


\draw (1.5,4.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 4
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[left] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (-90:11mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!11mm!-90:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[below] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!22mm!-140:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [right] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!22mm!-90:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,left] {$b$};
\draw [pink] (B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below] {$c$};
\draw [blue] (C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,below right] {$d$};
\draw [blue] (D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above right] {$e$};
\draw   (E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-1.9) node{$b=c,\;d=e$};
\draw (1,-2.5) node{$\widehat{B}=\widehat{D}=90^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (4.5,4.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 5
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:29mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!7mm!-120:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!15mm!-135:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [right] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!15mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw (B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [blue](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [blue](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1.2,-.9) node{$a=b,\;d=e$};
\draw (1.2,-1.5) node{$\widehat{A}=60^\circ,\;\widehat{D}=120^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,4.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 6
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:22mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!22mm!-40:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!9mm!-125:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!9mm!-140:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,above right] {$c$};
\draw [blue](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (.8,-.9) node{$a=d=e,\;b=c$};
\draw (.8,-1.5) node{$\widehat{B}+\widehat{D}=180^\circ,\;2\widehat{B}=\widehat{E}$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}

};


\draw (1.5,7.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 7
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:17mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!17mm!-140:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!17mm!-135:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!17mm!-90:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-.9) node{$b=c=d=e$};
\draw (1,-1.6) node{$\widehat{B}+2\widehat{E}=2\widehat{C}+\widehat{D}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (4.5,7.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 8
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.4]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:22mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!22mm!-110:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!22mm!-140:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!22mm!-70:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above left] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-.9) node{$b=c=d=e$};
\draw (1,-1.6) node{$2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=\widehat{D}+2\widehat{E}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,7.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 9
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.4]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:25mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!25mm!-75:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!25mm!-150:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!25mm!-60:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-1) node{$b=c=d=e$};
\draw (1,-1.7) node{$2\widehat{A}+\widehat{C}=\widehat{D}+2\widehat{E}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};


\draw (1.5,10.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 10
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:29.9mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!6mm!-110:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!18mm!-125:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [right] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!23mm!-145:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw ($ (A) + (0:23mm) $) coordinate (AA);
\draw ($(A) + (90:6mm)$) coordinate (EE);

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[white](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {\color{pink} $a$};


\draw[pink] (A) -- (AA);
\draw[blue] (B) -- (AA);
\draw (C) -- (D); 
\draw[pink] (D) -- (E);
\draw[pink] (E) -- (EE); 
\draw[blue] (A) -- (EE);

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (AA) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (EE) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1.3,-.9) node{$a=b=c+e$};
\draw (1.3,-1.55) node{$\widehat{A}=90^\circ,\;\widehat{B}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ$};
\draw (1.3,-2.2) node{
$\widehat{B}+2\widehat{C}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}

};
\draw (4.5,10.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 11
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.7]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:23.4mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!9mm!-150:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!18mm!-60:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!18mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};


\draw ($(C)!9mm!-60:(B)$) coordinate (CC);
\draw ($(CC)!4.5mm!0:(D)$ ) coordinate (CCC);
\draw ($(D)!4.5mm!0:(E)$) coordinate (DD);
\draw ($(DD)!4.5mm!0:(E)$) coordinate (DDD);



\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};


\draw[blue] (D) -- (DD);
\draw[blue] (DDD) -- (DD);
\draw[blue] (CC) -- (CCC);
\draw[blue] (CCC) -- (D);


\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);






\draw[fill] (CC) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (CCC) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (DD) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (DDD) circle (.6pt); 



\draw (1.5,-.8) node {$2a+c=d=e$ };
\draw (1.5,-1.45) node {$\widehat{A}=90^\circ,\;2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=360^\circ$};
\draw (1.5,-2.1) node {$\widehat{C}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,10.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 12
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:15mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!17mm!-155:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!26mm!-50:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!9mm!-115:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(C)!17mm! 0:(D)$) coordinate (CC);


\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw  (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above left] {$e$};
\draw[green](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[pink] (C) -- (CC);
\draw[blue] (CC) -- (D);
\draw[blue] (D) -- (E);


\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (CC) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1.4,-.9) node{$2a=d=c+e$};
\draw (1.4,-1.55) node{$\widehat{A}=90^\circ,\;2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=360^\circ$}; 
\draw (1.4,-2.2) node{$\widehat{C}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};


\draw (1.5,13.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 13
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:25mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!4.5mm!-90:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!24mm!-120:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!12mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(C)!12mm!0:(D)$) coordinate (CC);

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw  (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (CC) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1,-.9) node{$d=2a=2e$};
\draw (1,-1.55) node{$\widehat{B}=\widehat{E}=90^\circ$};
\draw (1,-2.2) node{$2\widehat{A}+\widehat{D}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (4.5,13.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 14
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:24.3mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!9mm!-145.34:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!18mm!-69.32:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!18mm!-124.66:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;

\draw ($(E)!9mm!0:(D)$) coordinate (EE);
\draw ($(D)!9mm!0:(C)$) coordinate (DD);

\draw (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (EE) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (DD) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1.4,-.9) node{$2a=2c=d=e,\,\widehat{A}=90^\circ$};
\draw (1.4,-1.55) node{$\widehat{B}\simeq 145.34^\circ,\, 
\widehat{C}\simeq 69.32^\circ$};
\draw (1.4,-2.2) node{$
 \widehat{D}\simeq 124.66^\circ,\, 
\widehat{E}\simeq 110.68^\circ$
%%(2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=360^\circ,\; \widehat{C}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ)
};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,13.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 15
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:21mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!10.5mm!-60:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!21mm!-135:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!10.5mm!-105:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(A)!10.5mm!0:(B)$) coordinate (AA);


\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [blue](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (AA) circle (.6pt);

\draw (.7,-.9) node{$a=c=e,\;b=2a$};
\draw (.7,-1.55) node{$
\widehat{E}=90^\circ,
\widehat{A}=150^\circ,
\widehat{B}=60^\circ$};
\draw (.7,-2.2) node{$
\widehat{C}=135^\circ,\;\widehat{D}=105^\circ$};
\end{tiny}
\end{tikzpicture}
};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: A very nice `tikz` demonstration.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes but not a question so off topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Segletes Before we close this, I think this would make an interesting package.  And perhaps we could use this question as an exercise on how to create a CTAN package from a question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps here would be a better place: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends

Comment: @R.Schumacher That is a question the OP might ask, but it is not something we can do as a response to this question, I don't think.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That would seem a good place, though `texample` is probably the better. (But they are not exclusive possibilities, of course.)